# JQuery hover fade with default div transition stutter

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I am attempting to use hover with with to swap div visibility when mousing over navigation buttons.
When there is no mouseover, there is a 'default' div that should appear.

My problem is that every time the mouse transitions between links, the default div briefly reappears.

Is it possible to make the swap seamless, or will a different approach to the swap work? I attempted to set the nav container div with a fadeout/fadein event for the default div, but I didn't have any luck with that.

Refer to the following fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ElectricCharlie/Wk8Yd/

```
$('div.hmnav').hover(function()
        {
        $('#_wnr00').stop(true,true).fadeOut();
        $('#_'+this.id).stop(true,true).fadeIn(400);
        },
        function ()
            {
        $('#_'+this.id).stop(true,true).fadeOut(400);
        $('#_wnr00').stop(true,true).fadeIn();      
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got rid of `true,true` and it worked fine:

```
$('div.hmnav').hover(function () {
    $('#_wnr00').stop().fadeOut();
    $('#_' + this.id).stop().fadeIn(400);
},

function () {
    $('#_' + this.id).stop().fadeOut(400);
    $('#_wnr00').stop().fadeIn();
});
```

Updated your jsFiddle as well.

**EDIT**: took the time to clean up your jQuery as well:

```
$('#navbox_inner')
    .corner("round 12px")
    .parent()
    .css({padding:1})
    .corner("round 14px")

$('#navbox_inner').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('#_wnr00').stop().fadeOut();
        $('#_' + this.id).stop().fadeIn(400);
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $('#_' + this.id).stop().fadeOut(400);
        $('#_wnr00').stop().fadeIn();
    }
},'.hmnav');
```

This is much faster, as it binds to one item, and delegates appropriately. I also removed the element selector, as a pure class based / id based selector is faster. Updated your jsFiddle a second time.

Comment: I changed it to .stop(false,true) because if I moused out of the div too quickly, the animation would stop without fully loading the transition. I left wnr00 as is (stop default is .stop(false, false), and that fixed all my issues.

Comment: just a heads up, you can get the behavior of `.stop(true,false)` from `.stop(1)`. It doesn't seem like much, but any way to shrink JS code size, the better.